# Java Use Hashmap from Session or else populate it in for loop

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having trouble understanding this. My scenario is this:

- I get the HashMap from the Session
- If the HashMap from session is not empty, use it in the for loop
- Else if the HashMap from session is empty, populate it in the for loop

My code is like this:

```
boolean isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty = false;
Map<String, Type> subscriberWithType = new HashMap<String, Type>();
Map<String, String> subscriberToCtnMap = getMapFromSession(HttpServletRequest)

if (subscriberToCtnMap == null || subscriberToCtnMap.isEmpty()) {
     isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty = true;
}

for (MobileNumber mobile : ListOfMobiles) {
     String subscriber = mobile.getSubscriberId();

     if (subscriber != null) {
          subscriberWithType.put(subscriber, Type.SUB_ID);
          if (isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty)
               subscriberToCtnMap.put(subscriber, mobile.getMobileNumber());
     } else {
          subscriberWithType.put(mobile.getMobileNumber(), Type.MOBILE);
          //No need to put the entry in subscriberToCtnMap as subscriber is NULL
     }
}

//Set the subscriberToCtnMap in Session if not set already
if (isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty) {
    session.setSubscriberToCtnMapping(subscriberToCtnMap);
}
```

How can I improve the coding quality of the above logic?

Thanks!

Comment: One suggestion can be for the line 
if (isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty)
               subscriberToCtnMap.put(subscriber, mobile.getMobileNumber());

When you are setting isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty to true, you check 2 conditions whether the list is null or is it empty. Suppose the list is null, then also the variable gets set to true. Now in your code, you just check the boolean value and assign value to the map, now consider the map is null, then your assignment code will fail, which will not happen if the map is not null and is empty.

Comment: I forgot to add that in getMapFromSession(HttpServletRequest), my first line is: Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String> () - so even if the session value is null I am getting a declared Map in response. So my "put" call will always happen on the empty Map (Map will never be null because it was declared in getMapFromSession() call)

Answer (score 0):

Your tests `if (isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty)...', no doubt intended to defend against the possibility of`subscriberToCtnMap` being null or empty, do exactly the opposite.  They should be like this:

```
if (!isSubscriberToCtnMapEmpty) { // added the ! (not) operator
   // only do this if if the map is NOT empty
}
```